# How to make the script to run through several files?

Tags: matlab

This is my code

```
function1( 'myfile.20140826')
plot( 'myfile.20140826.shd.mat', 1, 1, 1 )
saveas(gcf(), 'myfile.20140826.20140826.pdf') 

function1( 'myfile2.20140826' )
plot( 'myfile2.20140826.shd.mat', 1, 1, 1 )
saveas(gcf(), 'myfile2.20140826.pdf')
```

I have several files that I would like it to run and plot automatic. This file have almost the same name, but the date in the name changes (`myfile.20140826, myfile.20160827` ect.)Any ideas? Maybe make a for loop or something?

Comment: You can get all the file names with `dir`, and use the result to loop over the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the files you want to read in your directory and run:

```
Files=dir(fullfile(pwd,'\*.shd.mat'));
for j=1:length(Files)
 str=strsplit(Files(j).name,'.');
 res=sprintf('%s.%s',str{1},str{2});
 function1(res);
 plot(Files(j).name, 1, 1, 1 );
 saveas(gcf(), strcat(res,'.pdf'));
end
```

The command `dir(fullfile(pwd,'\*.shd.mat'))` will read all the files you have in your current folder.

Comment: On Linux you need the back-slash- `/`. But actually, on both OS you don't need it at all. `dir(fullfile(pwd,'*.shd.mat'))` will work.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Adiel's comment:

```
Files=dir('myfile*') %takes wildcards

for ii=1:length(Files)

   function1( Files(ii).name)
   % ...

end
```

Comment: It outputs a struct, one of who's fields is the name string